# how to match array of values from one table to another and dispaly matched values using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have two tables.
One is registration. From registration table i want to select username based on particular city.
And I also have second table from which I have to select Username whose active flag is set to true.
And from both tables i have to display those usernames which ae matched in both tables.
want immediate help.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: Do you have the 2 tables already and if you have them show us the schema of them? We need more information. You just need to make a simple query to resolve the problem and if you show us the design we could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let **$array1** and **$array2** are two arrays then:

```
$mached = array();
foreach($array1 as $val)
{
    if(in_array($val, $array2))
    {
        $mached[] = $val;
    }
}
```

the array **$matched** contains all the matched values...

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a query, not a PHP solution